# Heroku seed database with data not in seed.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have a Rails app and an AppKeys table. The AppKeys tables hold some configuration data that I do not want to expose. Currently, after pushing to Heroku, I need to run `heroku run rails console` and manually add the configuration data into the database.

I do not want to put the config data in `seed.rb` since the project is on Github.

I want to run `git push heroku master` and have it automatically seed the AppKeys table from a local ignored file.

Is there a way to automate this?

Comment: Have you considered using the [Figaro gem](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) for this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're looking for [release phase](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/release-phase).

If you set a `release` process type in your Procfile, it will be used for every new release (deploys, config vars changes, ...) to run a one-off dyno with that command.
The new release won't be used until that command succeeds.